# ReactJS - Charts from ChartJS re-rendering after first page load

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-hooks

I'm currently on a project that the use of charts is needed, so I opted for chartsjs, but I'm facing a small problem that have two parts.
[image]

1. When the page first loads my data is not being shown, and some graphs/data appear as undefined (I know that how it should work when I set some object like this “obj?.smt”), and I don't know if there's a way to mask it until the loading is done.
2. As you can see on the GIF whenever there's a reload on the page the graphs kinda flicker, and it kinda worries me, this page is going to have at least 50 graphs (not my idea), so if it's flickering does it mean that it's rendering 2 times? Or even more under the hood?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDreData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await http.get("/endpoint1");
        const data = await res.data;
        const final = data.data;
        // console.log(final);
        setEstimatedMonths(final);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
      }
    };
    const fetchProductsData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await http.get("/endpoint2");
        const data = await res.data;
        const final = data.data;
        // console.log(res);
        setEstimatedProducts(final);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
      }
    };
    fetchDreData();
    fetchProductsData();
  }, [control]);

  useEffect(() => {
    flatData();
  }, [estimatedProducts, estimatedMonths]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, [values]);
```

Quickly explaining what's happening over here. On the first `useEffect` there are 2 calls to different endpoints and the data from it is being set on two separate states. On the 2º one where `flatData()` is being called, some data from the 2 states are being manipulated because whoever did the backend decided that some stuff should be calculated on the front. And the last one is a big object where Data from everywhere comes together, is set in the graphs.

I don't know if those are being caused by some dumb mistake that I'm making, or it's just how ChartJS behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `console.log` or `console.count` to see how it executed.

My guess is that `flatData` called twice, when value of `estimatedProducts` changes and when value of `estimatedMonths` changes. If `values` come from there so first component doesn't have data, after one API call finished it set one state and update, on second API call it updates again.

You can combine 2 API calls in 1 function and set state 1 time.

Or put condition in useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (estimatedProducts && estimatedMonths) {
      flatData();
    }
  }, [estimatedProducts, estimatedMonths]);
```

Comment: Damn, I could not see at first lol, that was actually it, but now the problem is that all graphs are still blank after 1-2sec, do you think a ternary render can fix this? What do you think abt it?

Comment: Try to debug it, see what values have and if data passed to chart is correct.

Comment: Well, that was faster than i though, on the flatData function there was a state where some data was being set and used on my chart(), I used a ternary in the end.
`{values && chartData && ('graphs')}`
I don't know if it's the best way of approaching this problem, but it did work out just fine.

Comment: Fetching data from 2 endpoint for 1 chart isn't best way already, need to merge it and normalize. Can use Promise.all for 2 API calls, flat data and set state in 1 jump. Something like
```Promise.all([apiCall1, apiCall2]).then(([estimatedProducts, estimatedMonths]) => {
  setChartData( flatData(estimatedProducts, estimatedMonths) )
});```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't change how the backend work right now (it would be easier to send all the info at once), but I'm going to try the Promise.all.
Do you know if there's an async version of it? I'm using axios.

Comment: It should work with async/await, I just prefer promises and some wrapper for fetch.

Comment: Great! I think i'm going to need to study abt it for a little bit, first time ever hearing about this function.
Going to disect this here, if i'm wrong please correct me.
First I slap that into a function and call it on a useEffect, changing the apiCalls.
Second I would need to send the info as parameters to flatData.

Comment: But there is a problem, because the way I set up everything what is actually setting all chart data is `chart()`, not `flatData()`, flatData is only used to do some math.
But in the end that's a concern for another day, you actually helped me out here and gave me some ideas for what to do next. Thanks.